# Best way to setup conda init in a specific conda virtualenv?

Tags: conda, miniconda

which is the best way to setup a conda init directly into a specific conda virtualenv within linux (and not the **base** one)?

I noticed that there is no **conda init** additional parameter to specify a env.

My attempts to edit **./bashrc** were not effective

The original script is

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/conda/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/conda/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

The envs are under /opt/conda/envs/.../bin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not edit the `conda initialize` code section.

Rather,

1. Disable **base** auto-activation (once only, not in `.bashrc`):

   ```
   conda config --set auto_activate_base false
   ```
2. Add activation of the desired environment to the end of `.bashrc` (or similar):

   ```
   conda activate my_env
   ```